# Let the height of <p> determine height of <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a paragraph of text inside a `<div>` that varies with length and thus height. I want the div to have a minimum height of `100px`, but grows as the height of `<p>` increases above `80px`. I set the css property `height: 100px` for the `<div>` but when the `<p>` grew beyond `80px` the text just spills out of the `<div>` and the height of the `<div>` remains unchanged. What should I do?

**Code:**

```
<div id="outer_box">
    <div id="box">
        <p class="content"> Some long paragraph of content here </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#outer_box {
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 100px;
}

#box{
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 90px;
}
```

***The div with `id="box"` did change its height to contain the `<p>` entirely, but the div with `id="outer_box"` did not change its height!***

***Interested in a CSS solution rather than a jQuery one if possible, I will use whatever works. Reason for choosing a pure CSS solution is because the `div` does not exist until the user does a mouseover. Wonder how to target a `div` with css that have yet to exist***

Comment: Sounds like using min-height:100px could be an option but not supported in old browsers.

Comment: i dont wnt to support old browsers so its fine :)

Comment: Just use `min-height: 100px`. Only IE6 will have problems with that, which you just said you don't care about.

Comment: `min-height: 100px` does not seem to work. The `div` remained at 100px regardless of the height of the `<p>` within. I updated the original question to show the code

Comment: You can just write css rules as you normally would. They will be correctly applied whenever you render your divs.

Comment: @Amrit: The height of `outer_box` does not change to accomodate that of `box`, although the height of `box` does change to hold all of the `<p>` within it

Comment: Did you try using the break-word property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the min-height set on the div in your css, I would then use jquery's height function to figure out the paragraph height. Try this in your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var h = $('div p').height();
    $('div').css("height", h);
});
```

Comment: I'll use this method if there is no pure CSS method that works :)

Comment: Sanders: My divs do not exist until the user causes a `mouseover` event to fire. How should I target the div?

Answer (score 3):

As Jleagle said, you have to use `min-height`. For the most browsers:

```
height: auto !important;
height: 100px;
min-height: 100px;
```

Comment: why do I need `height: auto`?

Comment: To make "newer" browsers igonring the height property. The Internet Explorer will ignore "height: auto" and "min-height", but it handels "height" like "min-heigh".

Answer (score 0):

Append this to the styles of your div and everything should work fine, also for older browsers:

```
min-height:100px;
height:auto !important;
height:100px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Height of div when set to **auto** lets the content inside it decide its length. However **min-height** does an override and lets you have a min height for the div

Answer (score 0):

You set the `min-height` of the `div`, and then you deal with older version of IE via a standard CSS hack:

```
/* Because of the `* html` part, it only applies in IE, other browsers ignore it */
* html #theDiv {
  height: 100px;
}

/* Most browsers use this instead */
#theDiv {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ibewov)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the word-wrap property. I have tested the following styles in ie9 and chrome. It seems to be working fine.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
           <style>
            #outer_box {
                width: 300px;
                min-height: 100px;
                background-color:blue;
            }

            #box{
                width: 300px;
                background-color:green;
                word-wrap:break-word;
            }
            </style>

        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="outer_box">
                <div id="box">
                    <p class="content"> Some long paragraph of content here kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```